# Resposiveness in a website over 1200px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have been working on a website using bootstrap to make it responsive. But the problem arises when screensize goes beyond 1200px.
The website m talking about is e-commerce website so  m display 3 products in a row using col-*
Now when screen size is beyond 1500px i want it display 4 products in a row rather then limiting the size of the page in 1200px making a box

I hope it make sense
Ty

Comment: You need to show some code, explain more carefully how you want it to work and what it actually does, and ask a clear question

Comment: You could add a 2nd row with 4 elements below your 3 element row. and hide either one based on media query? that's the only way i can think off doing this without js

Comment: Yep now when i thinkn of it i shouldnadd more breaking point that bootstrap has to offer that way i can mame it responsive for learger screen size tyvm everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add the media query but revert the effect, `min-width` instead `max-width` for `1200px`, so will take from `1200px` and more, like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /*1200 and beyond*/

}
@media (max-width: 1200px) { /*Large Desktop*/

}
@media (max-width: 992px) { /*Desktop*/

}
@media (max-width: 768px) { /*Tablet*/

}
@media (max-width: 480px) { /*Large Phone*/

}
@media (max-width: 360px) { /*Medium Phone*/

}
@media (max-width: 320px) { /*Small Phone*/

}
```